# Prevent "Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)" on lldb

Tags: objective-c, lldb

I've written some code that dumps all ivars of a class into a dictionary in Objective C. This uses `valueForKey:` to get the data from the class. Sometimes, KVC throws an internal exception that is also captured properly - but this disrupts lldb's feature and all I get is:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

There are no breakpoints set. I even tried with `-itrue -ufalse` as expression options, but it doesn't make a difference. This totally defeats for what I want to use lldb for, and it seems like such a tiny issue. How can I bring clang to simply *ignore* if there are internal, captured ObjC exceptions while calling a method?

I tried this both from within Xcode, and directly via calling clang from the terminal and connecting to a remote debug server - no difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. My solution was to wrap a `try/catch` around it (I only use this code for debugging). See: [DALIntrospection.m](https://github.com/haShalosh/DALDebugging/blob/master/DALDebugging/DALDebugging/DALIntrospection.m) line #848

```
NSDictionary *DALPropertyNamesAndValuesMemoryAddressesForObject(NSObject *instance)
```

Or, if you're running on `iOS 7`, the private instance method `_ivarDescription` will print all the `ivars` for you (similar instance methods are `_methodDescription` and `_shortMethodDescription`).

Comment: The try/catch doesn't solve my original problem - you just work around it by only getting the value if it's an object. But I'll accept the answer because these new iOS 7 helpers are simply amazingly useful and will solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem.

My solution is simply `alloc init` the property before assigning it to the value which caused the crash.

Comment: Consider including a code snippet to improve your answer.

Comment: Try catch is not the correct solution but mollysmile.ye's is the correct solution

Answer (score 3):

Myself and coworkers ran into this today, and we eventually found a workaround using lldb's python API. The manual way is to run `script`, and enter:

```
options = lldb.SBExpressionOptions()
options.SetTrapExceptions(False)
print lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression('ThisThrowsAndCatches()', options).value
```

This could be packaged into its own command via `command script add`.

Comment: (working w/ swift ifacing objc) now, this helped in my wrapper of `expression` but i skipped `.value` and to replicate original's `--object-description` (aka `-O` / `po`) I added `.GetObjectDescription()` in its place, ie `print lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression(expression, options).GetObjectDescription()`. Oddly, this seems to be the only of SBExpressionOptions not controllable by `expression` options (see lldb `help`).

Answer (score 3):

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3).. The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Note that lldb specifically points to the internal breakpoint `-3` that caused the interruption.

To see the list of all internal breakpoints, run:

```
(lldb) breakpoint list --internal
...
Kind: ObjC exception
-3: Exception breakpoint (catch: off throw: on) using: name = 'objc_exception_throw', module = libobjc.A.dylib, locations = 1 
  -3.1: where = libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, address = 0x00007ff81bd27be3, unresolved, hit count = 4
```

Internal breakpoints can be disabled like regular ones:

```
(lldb) breakpoint disable -3
1 breakpoints disabled.
```

In case lldb continues getting interrupted you might also need to disable the conditions of the breakpoint:

```
(lldb) breakpoint disable -3.*
1 breakpoints disabled.
```

In my particular case there were multiple exception breakpoints I had to disable before I finally got the expected result:

```
(lldb) breakpoint disable -4 -4.* -5 -5.*
6 breakpoints disabled.
```